# How can i reference the player to get his/her position to be able to drop a item in front of the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey i was wondering if someone could help me getting the transform of a player then taking that and making a item drop in frount of the player i keep getting this error in unity saying "the name 'inFrontOfPlayer' does not exist in current context im also referencing the player with a

```cs
private Transform player;
```

This is the code if this is helpful or not

```cs
    public void CustomStart() 
    {
        defaultSprite = GetComponent<Image>().sprite;
        amountText = transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>();
        player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform;
    }

    private void Update() 
    {
        Vector3 inFrontOfPlayer = player.position + player.forward * 1;
    }

    public void DropItem()
    {
        if(slotsItem)
        {
            slotsItem.transform.parent = null;
            slotsItem.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            slotsItem.transform.position = inFrontOfPlayer;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you mean to make `inFrontOfPlayer` a class-level field?  Currently it's declared only in one method, and then immediately discarded.  Contrast that with the three (presumably) class-level fields you're setting in `CustomStart`.

Comment: yes thats what im trying to do so then i can just set the items position = to the players pos * 1 when they drop it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `inFrontOfPlayer` variable is placed within the Update() function's scope, meaning that once the function ends the variable is gone, and nothing else outside that scope (the curly brackets) can access it. The way to fix this is to declare the variable earlier in the file, like
`private Vector3 inFrontOfPlayer` at the start ,
and then using `inFrontOfPlayer = player.position + player.forward * 1;` in the update function. This means that the variable is now no longer in the scope of the update function meaning that it can be accessed by functions in the same class (or MonoBehaviour)
Example:

```
 public Transform player;
 private Vector3 inFrontOfPlayer;
 public void CustomStart() 
    {
        defaultSprite = GetComponent<Image>().sprite;
        amountText = transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>();
        player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform;
    }

    private void Update() 
    {
        inFrontOfPlayer = player.position + player.forward * 1;
    }

    public void DropItem()
    {
        if(slotsItem)
        {
            slotsItem.transform.parent = null;
            slotsItem.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            slotsItem.transform.position = inFrontOfPlayer;
        }
    }
```

Comment: remember to set an answer as the accepted answer so that the question is marked as "closed/answered" :) happy coding

Comment: yep i can do that in 1 minute as theirs a cool down after you create a question witch is weird

Answer (score 0):

Here you declare a class-level field:

```
private Transform player;
```

This field is available to any instance method in the class.  For example, you set a value to the field here:

```
public void CustomStart() 
{
    //...
    // Here:
    player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform;
}
```

But here you're declaring and setting a *local variable* in a method:

```
private void Update() 
{
    Vector3 inFrontOfPlayer = player.position + player.forward * 1;
}
```

Then the method ends and the variable and its value are discarded and never used.  If you want it to remain as a part of the class after the method ends and be available to other methods on that instance, make it a class-level field just like your other class-level fields:

```
private Vector3 inFrontOfPlayer;

// ...

private void Update() 
{
    inFrontOfPlayer = player.position + player.forward * 1;
}
```

Comment: Yep got it thanks!